# Calculate number of days from date time column to a specific date - pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a df as shown below.

df:

```
ID    open_date        limit
1     2020-06-03       100
1     2020-06-23       500
1     2019-06-29       300
1     2018-06-29       400
```

From the above I would like to calculate a column named `age_in_days`.
`age_in_days` is the number of days from open_date to `2020-06-30`.

Expected output

```
ID    open_date        limit     age_in_days
1     2020-06-03       100       27
1     2020-06-23       500       7
1     2019-06-29       300       367
1     2018-06-29       400       732
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `open_date` in datetime dtype and subtract it from `2020-06-30`

```
df['open_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.open_date)

df['age_in_days'] = (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-30') - df.open_date).dt.days


Out[209]:
   ID  open_date  limit  age_in_days
0   1 2020-06-03    100           27
1   1 2020-06-23    500            7
2   1 2019-06-29    300          367
3   1 2018-06-29    400          732
```